# Should I "require" a static image

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm getting started configuring webpack and I'm not sure the correct way to deal with static images and I've seen multiple approaches.

1. Don't require

I can create a directory for static files and then copy the static files with the copy-webpack-plugin.  My directory structure will look as such:

```
src/modules/login/components/loginPage.html
static/images/logo-login.png
```

2. Use require

I can rely on the html-loader to convert my image URL into a require statement and include my image alongside my code.  My directory structure will end up as:

```
src/modules/login/components/loginPage.html
src/modules/login/components/logo-login.png
```

Is there a correct method?  Are there pros & cons between the two (functionally they would behave differently as the require approach would inline the image)?  Or is it just personal preference?

Comment: Don't use the copy-webpack-plugin. Webpack is designed to give you actual management of your static asset dependencies like images. It uses `require()` in your source code to achieve this. Further reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to reference all assets via a `require` statement. This will tie you in with Webpack's module loading and you'll be able to configure how assets are transformed before they're finally exposed as a JS module via module loaders. For example, you might want to develop with raw images, but optimize them for I/O and create sets for different media.

`copy-webpack-plugin` allows you to add files from the context to the build output directly, without treating them as modules in a dependency graph. This has valid uses for documents which can be served directly by the server, like `robots.txt`, proofs for various appliances, local content generated by some other process, etc.

You will need to use both, but `copy-webpack-plugin` has a particular purpose.